SwiftUI Tap Gestures Not Responding in SwiftUI View After UIKit Interactive Transition Cancelled
I am using a custom UINavigationController with a custom pop animation and an interactive transition. The custom navigation controller works well for standard UIKit view controllers. However, when I push a UIHostingController that hosts a SwiftUI view, the SwiftUI view becomes unresponsive to tap gestures if the interactive transition is cancelled. The issue seems to occur specifically after the interactive transition is started and then cancelled.
This is  interactive transition code
class CustomPopAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from),
              let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else {
            return
        }

        containerView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -screenWidth / 3, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
            fromView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: screenWidth, y: 0)
            toView.transform = .identity
        }) { finished in
            fromView.transform = .identity
            toView.transform = .identity
            fromView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
    }
}


class CustomInteractiveTransition: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
    var hasStarted = false
    var shouldFinish = false

    override func cancel() {
        super.cancel()
        reset()
    }

    override func finish() {
        super.finish()
        reset()
    }

    private func reset() {
        hasStarted = false
        shouldFinish = false
    }
}


@objc
class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    private let customAnimator = CustomPopAnimator()
    private let customInteractiveTransition = CustomInteractiveTransition()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
        setupGesture()
    }

    private func setupGesture() {
        let edgeSwipeGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleEdgeSwipe(_:)))
        edgeSwipeGesture.edges = .left
        view.addGestureRecognizer(edgeSwipeGesture)
    }

    @objc private func handleEdgeSwipe(_ gesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        let progress = translation.x / view.bounds.width

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            customInteractiveTransition.hasStarted = true
            popViewController(animated: true)
        case .changed:
            customInteractiveTransition.shouldFinish = progress > 0.5
            customInteractiveTransition.update(progress)
        case .ended:
            customInteractiveTransition.hasStarted = false
            customInteractiveTransition.shouldFinish ? customInteractiveTransition.finish() : customInteractiveTransition.cancel()
        case .cancelled:
            customInteractiveTransition.hasStarted = false
            customInteractiveTransition.cancel()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return operation == .pop ? customAnimator : nil
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerFor animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return customInteractiveTransition.hasStarted ? customInteractiveTransition : nil
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let hostingController = viewController as? AIMAHostingController<SwiftUIView> {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                hostingController.view.setNeedsLayout()
                hostingController.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
}


SwiftUI code
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .id("123")
                .background(Color.green)
                .padding()
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("===onclick")
                }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


 let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())
        navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)


It seems its caused by moving view off screen using transform property, doing same with transform on layer should be some workaround (or keep atleast one pt of view on screen)
